# How to show category values in echo

Tags: php, html, mysql

```
$db_user="root";<br>
$db_pswd="";<br>
$db_host="localhost";<br>
$db_dbname="szabist";<br>

$db_con=mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pswd,$db_dbname);<br>
    if($db_con->connect_error){<br>
        die("connecting error" . $db_con->connect_error()); <br>
    }<br>

 $cat_query = $db_con->query('SELECT classname FROM category');<br>
$cat_row = mysqli_fetch_array($cat_query);<br>
echo '
    <table class="table-condensed">
        <tr>
            <td><label>Book Title:</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="book_title"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Category:</label></td>
            <td><select name="category_id">
            <option value="'.$cat_row['classname'].'">'.$cat_row["classname"].'</option>
            </select></td>
        </tr>';
```

Comment: <select name="category_id"><option value="'.$cat_row['classname'].'">'.$cat_row["classname"].'</option>
</select></td>

Comment: now, whats your problem ? you want to have select with option that contain value from your query ?

Comment: Write a question about your specific issue, we aren't here to guess. This `$cat_row = mysqli_fetch_array($cat_query);<br>` would throw an error...or I guess I wasted time reading, line 1 would throw an error..

Comment: Displaying only code does not explain what exactly your problem is! Please add some info

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: db_con in C:\xampp\htdocs\lmsys\php\require.php on line 213

Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\lmsys\php\require.php on line 213

Comment: Where is line 213? Update your question with additional information..

Comment: Br ????? Procedural with objected coroneted mysqli_fetch_array???

Comment: Use mysqli_query($db_con,"query");

Comment: thanks devpro, but its showing: Notice: Undefined variable: db_con in C:\xampp\htdocs\lmsys\php\require.php on line 214

Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\lmsys\php\require.php on line 214

Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\lmsys\php\require.php on line 215

Comment: mysqli_query($db_con,'SELECT classname FROM category');

Comment: Y r u using <br>???? Chk yur connection is fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$db_user="root";   
$db_pswd="";   
$db_host="localhost";    
$db_dbname="szabist";

$db_con=mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pswd,$db_dbname);
    if($db_con->connect_error){
        die("connecting error" . $db_con->connect_error); 
    }

function add_new_book(){

global $db_con;    

 $cat_query = $db_con->query('SELECT classname FROM category');
$cat_row = mysqli_fetch_array($cat_query);
echo '
    <table class="table-condensed">
        <tr>
            <td><label>Book Title:</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="book_title"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Category:</label></td>
            <td><select name="category_id">
            <option value="'.$cat_row['classname'].'">'.$cat_row["classname"].'</option>
            </select></td>
        </tr>';    }
```